# Найти максимальное количество одинаковых слов в списке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется список 
`words=['apple', 'apple', 'strawberry', 'banana', 'lemon']`
Нужно найти слово которые больше всех встречается в списке,сразу на ум приходит использование Counter,выводит:

```
Counter({'apple': 2, 'strawberry': 1, 'banana': 1, 'lemon': 1})
```

как мне обратиться к словарю чтобы он мне вывел "apple"(потому что это слово чаще всех встречается)

Comment: В цикле обойти все ключи и проверить все значения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [most_common](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) у [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), чтобы получить наиболее часто используемые элементы:

```
from collections import Counter

words = ['apple', 'apple', 'strawberry', 'banana', 'lemon']
counter = Counter(words)
print(counter)

# Одно слово, что чаще всех встречается
print(counter.most_common(1))  # [('apple', 2)]

# Выведем слово
word = counter.most_common(1)[0][0]
print(word)  # apple
```

Если у нас есть словарь, у которого значением будет количество (как [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)), то можно через `max` найти ключ с максимальным элементом:

```
# Найдем максимум, используя в качестве ключа второй элемент -- количество
word = max(counter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
print(word)  # apple
```

Тоже самое, что выше, но работаем с ключами словаря:

```
word = max(counter, key=counter.get)
print(word)  # apple
```